# How to get details in Matlab/Simulink about the error "Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object"?

Tags: matlab, struct, compiler-errors, simulink, dspace-ecu

I have a model designed with Matlab/Simulink R2017a and it is running well with no errors or warning messages in Diagnostic Viewer or MATLAB Command Window when I run it diretly from the Simulink.

However, when I start a build process on ConfigurationDesk from dSPACE to use this model in an embedded application the build process is aborted and the following message is shown:

```
Could not generate model code for model 'Model'. See MATLAB Command Window for details.
```

In MATLAB Command Window the following message is shown:

```
Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
================================================================================
    Aborted Model-Code Generation for Model "Model".
================================================================================
```

As you can observe In MATLAB Command Window, there is no enough details about the error and due that I'm not being able to fix it.

There is any way to get more details about the error in order to track down it?

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: does your code create a variable `Model`? if so, use a different identifier. Try changing the variable named `Model` in your code to something else.

Comment: This error means somewhere there is a statement like `X = foo.bar;` where Matlab would normally read the content of field `bar` from structure `foo`. However, `foo` is not a structure so the operation fails with this message (it could be an empty array, a numeric array, a char array, a cell array...).

Comment: see comment from @Brice above. It indeed looks like a variable that is a structure in your MATLAB session has been overwritten by your build environment.